# Output items won't display properly inside a div with class = "target"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on adding some functionality to hide/reveal sections of an app. The code below does what I want it to in terms of hiding/revealing portions of the page, however, the verbatimTextOutput doesn't display properly when inside the `div(class = "target")` element.

```
ui <- basicPage(
# Adds CSS for links to work correctly
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
.target > div {
  display:none;
}

.target > div:target{
  display:block;
}"))
  ),

  # Adds links
  a("Page 1",href = "#p1"),
  a("Page 2", href = "#p2"),

  # Pages for links
  verbatimTextOutput("works")

  div(class = "target",
      div(id = "p1",
          verbatimTextOutput("doesnt")
          ),
      div(id = "p2",
          "Other page")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$works <- renderPrint("Yay!")

  output$doesnt <- renderPrint("Hello")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried changing the `display:none;` to `display:hidden`, but that doesn't seem to help at all.

It definitely has to do with the `display:none;` property. If I change the CSS to something else (like changing the border from dotted to solid) it works just fine. See the code for that below:

```
ui <- basicPage(
# Adds CSS for links to work correctly
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
.target > div {
  border-style:dotted;
}

.target > div:target{
  border-style:solid;
}"))
  ),

  # Adds links
  a("Page 1",href = "#p1"),
  a("Page 2", href = "#p2"),

  # Pages for links
  verbatimTextOutput("works"),

  div(class = "target",
      div(id = "p1",
          verbatimTextOutput("doesnt")
          ),
      div(id = "p2",
          "Other page")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$works <- renderPrint("Yay!")

  output$doesnt <- renderPrint("Hello")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So the question now is how do you get shiny to render UI elements inside an undisplayed div?

The problem with the display:none property is discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/yxFuGgDOIuM